# Function that is called when UILabel initializes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to subclass `UILabel`. The first try involves that my custom `UILabel` simply sets the property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`. The problem is that I am new to iOS programming and unsure about where to put this code. I tried the code below but they are never called.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSLog(@"init custom label");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
}
return self;
}

- (id)init
{
NSLog(@"init custom label");
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
}

return self;
}
```

I got it to work by using:

```
lblCustom = [lblCustom init];
```

But is there someway I can get this call to be called automatically?

Comment: Are using you custom label in the interfacebuilder (xib or storyboard)?

Comment: -initWithCoder: is the method you're looking for if you label is create with interfacebuilder

Comment: Go to identity inspector in your label in XIB and change the class name from UILabel to your customlabel and override the initwithCoder method in you custom label class

Comment: more info ...... http://stackoverflow.com/q/32662344/294884

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a label is used in interface builder is then the coded use the [`NSCoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) protocol:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"init custom label");
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
       // Initialization code here.
       self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

What I do, is create one method to setup my custom UI object and let all the init call this method.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally stay away from `initWithCoder:` and instead use `awakeFromNib` instead. Here is why ([Apple UIKit Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib)):

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and
>   action connections already established.

I have a variety of UI subclasses in my program and here is the solution I came up in my `BaseLabel` class.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self)
    {
        // We were not loaded from a NIB
        [self labelDidLoad:NO];
    }

    return self; 
}

- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // We were loaded from a NIB
    [self labelDidLoad:YES]; 
}

- (void)labelDidLoad:(BOOL)loadedFromNib
{
    // Do some initialization here...
}
```

Now all of my subclasses simply override `{type}didLoad:(BOOL)loadedFromNib`.

For example `buttonDidLoad:`, `textFieldDidLoad:`, and `tableViewDidLoad:` (you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

Calling only init on an UIView is the same as calling initWithFrame: with a zero-rect. So you should override initWithFrame or initWithCoder if you are using nib-files.