# Resolve recursion in Swift property override

Tags: ios, swift, properties

Here's a simple extension in Swift, for UILabel,

```
let dur=0.1 // (set to say 2.0 to see the effect more clearly)
extension UILabel
    {
    func change(s:String)->()
        {
        print("attempting 'change' with \(s)")
        UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
            animations: { self.alpha = 0.2 },
            completion:
                { _ in
                self.text = s      ///CCC
                UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
                    animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 })
                })
        }
    }
```

with a UILabel, simply do this

```
aLabel.change("hello there")
```

It will quickly blend from the old to the new text. No problem.

Of course, it would be better if we could write this ...

```
aLabel.text = "hello there"
```

To do that, just make a new UILabel class, with a new version of the ".text" property.

```
class CoolLabel:UILabel
    {
    override var text:String?
        {
        get { return super.text }
        set { super.change(newValue!) } //PROBLEM! AAA
        }
    }
```

But!  It doesn't work: it goes in to an endless loop.

Notice the "self.text" in the change() extension: at that point it goes in to a loop.

(I also tried `set { self.change(newValue!) }` and it does not work.)

The following works perfectly:

```
class TOLabel:UILabel
    {
    override var text:String?
        {
        get { return super.text }
        set
            {
            UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
                animations: { self.alpha = 0.2 },
                completion:
                    { _ in
                    super.text = newValue //BBB
                    UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
                        animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 })
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

That's fine, but what am I doing wrong in the first version?

How would you write the setter to successfully use the .change extension?

---

By the way, for anyone reading here is how you would more fully subclass IBLabel, you have to override the designated initialiser, and, you'll need to keep a local "realtime" version of text so that the getter replies correctly during animations, immediately after you set the text.

```
class TOLabel:UILabel
    {
    private var _text:String?
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
        {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self._text = super.text;
        }
    override var text:String?
        {
        get { return self._text }
        set {
            self._text = newValue;
            UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
                animations: { self.alpha = 0.2 },
                completion:
                    { _ in
                    super.text = self._text
                    UIView.animateWithDuration( dur,
                        animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 })
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is one of the instances when you need to bypass the setter. You need to use`super.text` in your change method just as you do in your last code example.

Comment: But the thing is. At my comment `//PROBLEM` I am indeed sending the SUPER to "change".  But when `change` operates at the 6th line of `change`, it operates on the TOLabel, not on the super...  :O

Comment: Right.  The problem you have is that you can't bypass the setter, so you can't avoid recursion.  To be honest the subclass is probably the better approach anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I believe you but I don't see why i can say "super.text=" at BBB, but I can't say super.text at CCC by calling `change` at AAA.

Comment: Because when you are executing code in the context of your subclass, super.text doesn't call your subclass setter.  When you execute `change` it calls the setter for `self.text` which is the subclasses setter, which causes recursion. If you implement change in your subclass (where it probably belongs) you could use `super.text` and you won't have a problem

Comment: Ah!  You've made me realise I have both an **extension to** UILabel and a **subclass** of UILabel.  There's the rub.  Really you should pop in an answer for the sake of future googlers, Paulw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion is called when you use `self.text=` to assign a new value in your `change` extension method because this will call the setter, which calls `change` and so on.

In your second example, you avoid recursion because you can call the superclass setter from your subclass setter.  You don't have this option in your extension **because your code is running as an extension to `UILabel` and therefore there is no superclass setter** to call.

Arguably creating a subclass rather than using extension is the more correct approach in this instance anyway